# Find $E[X^2]$ if $X$ is the number of points in a square within the inscribed circle

Tags: probability

We try to approximate $\pi$ by choosing random points in a square and seeing if they lie within the inscribed circle. The probability that a point is in the circle is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Suppose we choose $k$ points at random, then $E[X]$ = $\frac{\pi k}{4}$. I'm trying to calculate $E[X^2]$.

#### Progress

One thing I can deduce is that $X = \sum^k_{j=1} I_j$, where $I_j$ is 1 if the $j$'th point is in the circle and $0$ if not.

Then $\sum^k_{j=1} I_j = \sum_{j \not = i} I_i I_j + \sum^k_{j=1}I_j I_j$, but how can we find the expected value of the terms within the sums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway,

$E[X^2]=E[X(X-1)]+E[X]=\sum_{x=0}^k x(x-1)\frac{k!}{x!(k-x!)}p^x(1-p)^{k-x}+kp=$
$=k(k-1)p^2\sum_{x=2}^k \frac{(k-2)!}{(x-2)!(k-x!)}p^{x-2}(1-p)^{k-x}+kp=$
$=k(k-1)p^2\sum_{y=0}^m \frac{m!}{y!(m-y!)}p^{y}(1-p)^{m-y}+kp=k(k-1)p^2 \cdot 1+kp$

Then plug $p=\pi/4$